# Install typescript for Ubuntu via npm vs using native packges (via apt)

Tags: typescript, ubuntu, npm, apt

I want to add typescript to my Ubuntu and there are two methods for that:

1. sudo apt update && sudo apt install node-typescript -y
2. sudo npm install -g typescript

My question is more than just typescript, I want to know whether there is a benefit in any of those ways. Probably the native packages are not the very latest version so npm wins, or on the other hand, apt may prepare more control on update or maintenance. How can these 2 approaches be compared?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad How do npm and apt work defer inside Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. If you want to make sure that you have access to the latest releases and that the releases are official, the distribution on npm is published and maintained by the TypeScript team while the node-typescript distribution you're installing via apt is, AFAIK, not. This question really specific to Ubuntu, Linux, or even npm.

Comment: @AluanHaddad So it seems there's nothing more to dig, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Official Installation

The official TypeScript [download page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/download) lists three ways for the installation, via:

- a npm module
- a NuGet package
- a Visual Studio extension

They present the following install command: `npm install typescript --save-dev`

### Difference

As one of the official ways covers the **TypeScript npm module** (which can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript)), you can be sure that it provides the latest release, published by the TypeScript team itself.

For a specific Linux distro, the executables are provided, maintained, and published by the team responsible for that distro's package manager. So you may end up with an outdated version of TypeScript ‍♂️.

For example, with Ubuntu you can find all the **TypeScript apt packages** [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=node-typescript).